# could any one tell me how to calculate the following limit?

Tags: real-analysis

could any one tell me how to calculate the following limit?

$f_n(x)=n^{p+1}x\text{ if } x\in[0,{1\over n}]$ and ${1\over x^p} \text{if } x\in ({1\over n},1]$

well, when $x=0$ we have $f(x)=0$, for some $x={1\over n}$ we have $f(x)=n^p$ which is $0$ iff $p\le -1$

again when $x=1$ we have $f(x)=1$

I can not do more, please help me

Comment: Is there a range for the values of p?

Comment: Fix an x and let n go to infinity, what happens?  Good that you checked x=0 already.

Comment: I.e does it make sense to look at an $n$ dependent $x$ value?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Take a fixed $x$, like $x=0.123$. What does $f_n(x)$ approach as $n$ gets large?